# Sub-selection based on function

Tags: d3.js

I have a selection of elements that I'm trying to filter down based on a particular style value (I want just the ones with opacity=1).  I'm looking at the documentation for [selection.filter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) along with [selection.select](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-select) and [selection.selectAll](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-selectAll) as well but I'm confused about the correct usage with a function argument.

"select" indicates that it selects the first matching element (as expected) but then the example in the filter documentation shows it being used with a function to select the "odd" elements while maintaining the index.

"selectAll" indicates that you can return an array of elements, but that the function argument is invoked one-by-one in the usual way for each element in the original selection. I'm having difficulty imagining a use case for this.

I guess what I'm wondering is whether there are any tutorials or examples around that discuss the correct usage of these functions?

Thanks,
scott

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to reduce a selection to a subset of selected elements, use **filter**. If you want to select descendent elements, use **select** or **selectAll**.

Most often, filter is used to filter elements based on data or index. However, you can access the selected element as `this` within the filter function. Thus, if you have some elements selected, and you want to reduce that selection to only those elements with an opacity of 1, you can say:

```
var opaque = selection.filter(function() {
  return this.style.opacity == 1;
});
```

To be safe, you might prefer to look at the [computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) rather than the element's style properties. This way, if the opacity is inherited from a stylesheet, you'll get the correct value; otherwise, when a style is inherited `this.style.opacity` will be the empty string.

```
var opaque = selection.filter(function() {
  return window.getComputedStyle(this, null).getPropertyValue("opacity") == 1;
});
```

Or equivalently, select the node and use [selection.style](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-style):

```
var opaque = selection.filter(function() {
  return d3.select(this).style("opacity") == 1;
});
```

You might find it easier if you filter by data or by class, instead of by computed style property. For example, if you set a class on your nodes, you can filter a selection by class instead:

```
var opaque = selection.filter(".opaque");
```

Comment: That makes complete sense for filter (and your last code snippet is almost exactly what I ended up with in my code).  But I'm not quite clear about select and selectAll with a function argument.  How can the function be used to select descendent elements?  Thanks again.

Comment: You'd only use select or selectAll with a function if you didn't want to use a selector string, such as ".foo". For example, you could say `selection.select(function() { return this.firstChild; })` to select the first child of every selected node.